# PHPMailer $mail->addAttachment attatchment missing sometime

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am sending emails with attachments using PHPMailer. Generally files are images with jpg png jpeg formats. Sometime images are attaching to email but sometime it is missing.
I am using the code as below.

```
for($i=0; $i < $count_rows; $i++){     
    $root_dr = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $img_url_dr = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $passport_attachment = str_replace($img_url_dr, $root_dr, $all_images[$i]); 
    $mail->addAttachment($passport_attachment, $all_data['firstname'][$i]); 
}
```

It is working perfactly with attachments but sometimes attachments fails I am confused where the problem is.
Images in loop can be 1 to 5 images in a loop.
Please help where i am doing wrong and why sometime attachments missed?

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the return value from `addAttachment`, and your loop is a bit inefficient. Do this:

```
$root_dr = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$img_url_dr = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
for($i=0; $i < $count_rows; $i++){     
    $passport_attachment = str_replace($img_url_dr, $root_dr, $all_images[$i]); 
    if !($mail->addAttachment($passport_attachment, $all_data['firstname'][$i])) {
        echo "File $passport_attachment failed to attach\n";
    }
}
```

It's hard to tell from your code whether you're doing this (I don't now what's in `$all_images`), but `addAttachment` does expect a local path, not a URL to the file you want to attach.